# ¿Cómo auto-rellenar campo en tabla Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Voy a ilustrar lo que deseo hacer con un ejemplo simple:

Tengo la siguiente tabla, el campo “TEST” de tipo NUMBER es nuevo y no tiene valores:

```
|ID |    NAME    | TEST |
|---|------------|------|
|1  | Stark      |      |
|5  | Targaryen  |      |
|9  | Lannister  |      |
```

Necesito auto-rellenar el campo TEST con números consecutivos iniciando en 1. Es decir obtener algo como:

```
|ID |    NAME    | TEST |
|---|------------|------|
|1  | Stark      |   1  |
|5  | Targaryen  |   2  |
|9  | Lannister  |   3  |
```

Utilizo una base de datos ORACLE 11g y me conecto por medio de Toad.

Comment: ¿Lo debes hacer directamente en la base de datos? ¿Cuál es el criterio de ordenamiento? ¿Qué pasará si eliminas una fila de la tabla? Me parece que esta clase de cosas funcionan mejor si se hace en el *front-end* en lugar de en la base de datos

Comment: 1) Si, se debe hacer directamente en la base de datos, es un paso para normalizar una tabla. 2) no hay criterio de ordenamiento. 3) Qué puede provocar que se elimine una fila de la tabla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si acabas de crear la nueva columna con los valores puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
UPDATE mitabla SET test = ROWNUM;
```

En Oracle ROWNUM es una pseudocolumna que en este caso regresará en número de fila y lo asignará a tu columna. Este método aplica para un sólo uso, porque si eliminas filas intermedias y vas a seguir añadiendo filas pueden ocurrir inconsistencias en la numeración. Pero es muy útil si no deseas crear un objeto de esquema.

Answer (score 4):

Lo que tienes que hacer es crear una `secuencia` y actualizar tu tabla usando dicha secuencia. Lo puedes hacer así:

```
create sequence seq1;
```

Esta es una secuencia que se autoincrementa de 1 en 1 y el primer valor que te dará es `1`. Sin valor máximo. Si quieres incrementar de 2 en 2 o poner un máximo o un nuevo valor inicial, puedes añadirle parámetros a la creación de dicha secuencia, así:

```
create sequence seq1 start with 1 increment by 1 minvalue 1 maxvalue 100000;
```

Luego actualizas tu tabla:

```
update tu_tabla set test=seq1.nextval;
```

Si ya hay valores insertados en la columna `test` por alguna razón, sugiero usar esta versión:

```
    update tu_tabla set test=seq1.nextval where test is null;
```

El resultado debería ser algo así:

```
|ID |    NAME    | TEST |
|---|------------|------|
|1  | Stark      |   1  |
|5  | Targaryen  |   2  |
|9  | Lannister  |   3  |
```

También puedes hacerlo como sugiere [enrique](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/1462/enrique7mc):

```
UPDATE mitabla SET test = ROWNUM;
```

pero hay algo que no me gusta de eso y es que si por alguna razón eliminaras una fila intermedia y sigues agregando valores a la tabla, entonces se hará un desorden en el campo `test` porque no cumplirá con el número de fila.

Por otro lado, si eliminas valores intermedios usando una secuencia, el siguiente valor de la secuencia se mantiene aunque hayas eliminado algunos anteriores.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías manejarlo con una secuencia:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE NOMBRE_SECUENCIA START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999; -- Aquí tu máximo valor
```

Y luego actualizas el campo

```
UPDATE TuTabla SET TEST = NOMBRE_SECUENCIA.NEXTVAL;
COMMIT;
```